# function Max in query AS400

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have one file (name File1) who is like that:

```
AGE    NAME (names are unique)
10     john
20     fred
10     james
15     jack
20     alfred
20     henry
```

and I would like to get the name of the olders with one query:

```
AGE     NAME
20     fred
20     alfred
20     henry
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, use MAX.  What did you try?  What error did you get?

Answer (score 3):

SQL:

```
SELECT AGE, NAME FROM File1 WHERE AGE = (SELECT MAX(AGE) FROM File1)
```